# how to calculate the height of a BST in python

Tags: python, binary-search-tree

I've created a BST. and now I want to find the height of the BST developed.

Here is my code for constructing the **BST**

```
class Node:
    '''represents a new node in the BST'''
    def __init__(self,key):
        self.key=key
        self.disconnect()
    def disconnect(self):
        self.left=None;
        self.right=None;
        self.parent=None;
    def __str__(self):
        return 'node with kay %s'%self.key

class BST:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root=None

    def insert(self,t):
        '''inserts a new element into the tree'''
        if self.root is None:
            self.root = Node(t)
        else:
            self._do_insert(self.root,t)

    def _do_insert(self,parent,t):
        if t > parent.key:
            if parent.left is None:
                parent.left = Node(t)
            else:
                self._do_insert(parent.left,t)
        elif t < parent.key:
            if parent.right is None:
                parent.right = Node(t)
            else:
                self._do_insert(parent.right,t)
        else:
            # raise a KeyError or something appropriate?
            pass
```

I've a list of numbers (`[2,4,6,3,190,1,56 and so on]`) via which this BST is constructed.

Now I want to find the height of the BST created. How can I do that?

**EDIT**

As per the solution provided I tried this :-

```
def create_bst(values):

    '''Creates a BST and returns the BST created object'''
    BSTobj = BST()

    for i in values:
        BSTobj.insert(i)

    return BSTobj


def height_of_BST(bst):

    '''Returns the height of the BST created'''
    if bst == None: return 0
    else: return 1 + max(height_of_BST(bst.left), height_of_BST(bst.right))


print height_of_BST(create_bst(unique_values))
```

And its not working. It pops up an error saying `BST instance has no attribute 'left'`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The height of a nonempty binary search tree is 1 + the height of its tallest subtree, or just 1 if it has no children. This translates pretty directly to a recursive algorithm. In pseudocode:

```
def height(bst):
    if isempty(bst):
        return 0
    else:
        return 1 + max(height(bst.left), height(bst.right))
```

Comment: Thanks for it. I'm quite new to python, hence was not able to decode the pseudocode into actual code. Here what I tried. I inserted the values inside the BST, then returned the BSTobj to this function. I modified it like this `def height_of_BST(bst):
 if bst == None: return 0
 else: return 1 + max(height(bst.left), height(bst.right))`. How do I represent `bst.left` and `bst.right` ?

Comment: I've edited my question with what I've tried. Kindly have a look at it and please rectify the errors. Thanks

Comment: @python-coder: You're pretty close. This algorithm works on nodes, not the BST class. You just need to have a helper function that extracts the BST's root and passes it to the height function. Something like `def height(self): return node_height(self.root)`.

Comment: How do I extract the root of the BSt? Do I need to walk down the BST? I didnt understood. Can you please provide a sample code? Thanks!!!

Comment: @python-coder: The root of the BST is `self.root`. No traversal needed; just access the `root` attribute.

Comment: So, should it be like this `def height(self,root):
     if self.root == None: return 0
     else: return 1 + max(height(self.root.left), height(self.root.right))`

Comment: No. First, you're not doing anything with the `root` argument. Second, I mean that you should define a `node_height` function that works with nodes, then have the height method for BSTs call `node_height` on the BST's root. For example, in the BST class: `def height(self): return node_height(self.root)`, and not in a class: `def node_neight(node): if node is None: return 0 else: return 1 + max(node_height(node.left), node_height(node.right))`.

Comment: If you are told that the height of the BST is the number of nodes from root to the farthest node, which means a tree with only root has 0 height, then you just have to change the `return 0` into `return -1`.

Answer (score 1):

The BST in your class is actually stored in BST.root not in BST. You need to modify your code to look at BST.root instead of BST.

Try:

```
def height(BST):
    return actual_height(BST.root)
def actual_height(bst_node):
    if bst_node is None:
        return 0
    else:
        return 1 + max(actual_height(bst_node.left), actual_height(bst_node.right))
```

This defines a helper function that does the actual work but lets you just call height on the BST object. In the future, you might just want to only have a `Node` class because your BST class is basically just a wrapper around the `root` value.

Answer (score 0):

The interpreter is complaining because you didn't check for cases where the node has no children. If a node has no children it heigth is -1
  here a solution

`def height(bst):
    if bst == None :
        return -1
    else:
        return 1 + max(height(bst.left), height(bst.right))`

Comment: root has height 1.

Answer (score -1):

You can use hasattr to check if the object has the attr, if not you get to the end of the tree

```
def height(bst_node):
     if not hasattr(bst_node, 'left') or not hasattr(bst_node, 'right'):
         return 0
    else:
        return 1 + max(height(bst_node.left), height(bst_node.right))
```